Display error on a Remote RaspberryPi connected via SSH
I am running a Tkinter window on a remote Raspberry Pi with a display.
I want to see the Tkinter GUI on the display of RPi. I am connected to the RPI via Putty(SSH, from a Windows PC). RPi has a 64-bit full desktop OS.
When running the code on the Putty, the following error is generated.

Error:  no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable

How to solve this?? The code works correctly if I run it directly on the RPI terminal.
Note:
I've already tried the following. But No luck.
if os.environ.get('DISPLAY','') == '':
   print('no display found. Using :0.0')
   os.environ.__setitem__('DISPLAY', ':0.0')


(a) The system from which you are ssh-ing needs an X11 display server, and (b) your ssh client needs to be configured to forward X11 display connections. I'm not familiar with Windows, so I don't know what your options are for (a), and I don't know if PuTTY supports (b).

Did you get the message "no display found.  Using :0.0" when you executed the script?  Note that if DISPLAY is not set, os.environ.get('DISPLAY') returns None not empty string.  Also it is better to use os.environ['DISPLAY'] = ... instead of calling __setitem__().

From python, try:
if 'DISPLAY' not in os.environ:
    os.environ['DISPLAY'] = ':0'

You can also start your app like that:
DISPLAY=:0 python app.py


I found the following solution worked for me.
if the Raspberry Pi has a login screen (enter password to unlock when powered on)

•    Then, the display variable is 1
•    Else the display variable is 0

I changed the display variable to 1 and it worked.
if os.environ.get('DISPLAY','') == '':   
    print('no display found. Using :0.0')
    os.environ.__setitem__('DISPLAY', ':1')

